# numpy: Different results between diff and gradient for finite differences

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate the numerical derivative of two arrays `a` and `b`.

If I do

```
c = diff(a) / diff(b)
```

I get what I want, but I loose the edge (the last point) so `c.shape ~= a.shape`.

If I do

```
c = gradient(a, b)
```

then `c.shape = a.shape`, but I get a completely different result.

I have read how gradient is calculated in numpy and I guess it does a completely different thing, although I dont understand quite well the difference yet. But is there a way or another function to calculate the differential which also gives the values at the edges?

And why is the result so different between `gradient` and `diff`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions, although related, do different actions.

`np.diff` simply takes the differences of matrix slices along a given axis, and used for `n`-th difference returns a matrix smaller by `n` along the given axis (what you observed in the `n=1` case). Please see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

`np.gradient` produces a set of gradients of an array along all its dimensions while preserving its shape https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html Please also observe that `np.gradient` should be executed for one input array, your second argument `b` does not make sense here (was interpreted as first non-keyword argument from `*varargs` which is meant to describe spacings between the values of the first argument), hence the results that don't match your intuition.

I would simply use `c = diff(a) / diff(b)` and append values to `c` if you really need to have `c.shape` match `a.shape`. For instance, you might append zeros if you expect the gradient to vanish close to the edges of your window.